# How Instagram About Us page works?

Tags: tabs, url-rewriting, instagram

Let's start from this page: http://instagram.com/about/us/

The URL has this: /about/us. If I go to Jobs, the URL is this: http://instagram.com/about/jobs/

How can I do something similar to this? It's like vertical tabs right? The anchor tags ha this: href="/about/jobs/"

How is this works? URL rewrite? Or what? I want to implement something similar to this in my site.

Comment: That's a regular hyperlink.  What don't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .htaccess for this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about/us/?$ link/to/site.html
RewriteRule ^about/jobs/?$ link/to/site2.html
```

What I would do is use a framework for this like zend or symfony (if your into php).